# Time Limit Exceeded Error

Tags: email, developer-console, debug

I currently have a page that would send email notification to other users including attachments. But if the number of receivers is too many, I would often get an error `Time Limit Exceeded`. This is probably because I am sending an email to many users while having an attachment with the size(in total) of more than 5 MB. Now, I want to figure out which part of the code is taking a lot of time. How do I know this using my debug log in developer console?

Answer (score 3):

In the developer console, have a look around the Execution Overview window. In particular, the Timeline tab. It should give you a quick visual representation of where more of the execution time is going.

[image]

See also: [Evaluating the Performance of a Visualforce Page](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_dev_console_solving_problems_using_system_log.htm&language=en_US)